# facing problem with Word 2016 , 2010 and 2013 table and text mismatch

Tags: visualforce, document

I am facing a problem where I'm generating Word docs from custom VF pages, I'd built these pages for Word 2010 , however, all the tables and text are a little out of shape for Word 2016.
This is mainly to do with alignment mismatch in Word 2010, 2013 and 2016.

Hoping someone has a way to generate Word docs from custom VF pages uniformly along all versions of MS Word.

Thanks!